# Docker container No such file directory found

Tags: python, docker

I am a new learner of Docker. I tried to build an image to run a previously written program package that is designed to run in a Linux environment. The package also uses a makefile and Make command to run. 
Below is my Dockerfile

```
  FROM ubuntu:latest

  FROM python:latest

  ADD . / 

  WORKDIR /

  RUN pip install virtualenv

  RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

  CMD make all
```

My idea is to do it as simple as possible. In this case, I want to build a Linux image to let me run the makefile. The above Dockerfile allowed to build an image successfully. But when I run it, I got

*FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/TGM-code/data/processed/MICAB/file.tsv*

when the container starts to run the python scripts.

I have placed the Dockerfile at the parental directory, and not changed the file directory structure at all. Please help me understand what is my problem.

Comment: If you `docker run --rm -it yourimage /bin/sh` to get a debugging shell on the image, are the files there?